# Is it possible to create a type guard to check whether an object field is undefined?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to come up with typings for a code I write. Suppose I have following interfaces:

```
interface Car {
    id: string;
    type: number
    ownerId: number | undefined;
    // ... other fields
}

interface Plane {
    id: number;
    ownerId: number | undefined;
    // ... other fields
}
```

I will often use them with `Array` methods like so:

```
const fCars = cars
    .filter(car => car.ownerId !== undefined)
    .filter(car => car.type === 1)

const fPlanes = planes
    .filter(plane => plane.ownerId === 1)

// fCars and fPlanes are Car[] and Planes[] respectively
```

Because a lot of predicates are either similar or pretty much the same,
I wanted to export them as functions to achieve result like following code:

```
const filtered = cars
    .filter(byDefined('ownerId'))
    .filter(byEq('type', 1))

const filtered = planes
    .filter(byEq('ownerId', 1))

// for some fields, I would like to shorten this even further to just

const filtered = planes
    .filter(byOwnerIdEq(1))
```

I've managed to come up with `composeEqual` function that compares any field to a value of known type:

```
export const composeEqual =
    <
        Key extends string,
        Value extends unknown,
        CheckType extends { [key in Key]: Value },
        Type extends CheckType
    >(
        key: Key,
        value: Value
    ) =>
    (obj: Type): obj is Type & CheckType =>
        obj[key] === value;

export const byOwnerIdEq = (ownerId: string) => composeEqual('ownerId', ownerId);
```

However this still doesn't solve my problem fully - when a field's type is a union, TS report an error.
Going back to my previous example

```
const filtered = cars
    .filter(byDefined('ownerId'))
    .filter(byEq('type', 1)) // error
```

I would like `byDefined` function to type guard `cars` from `ownerId` possibly being undefined.

The new type should be:

```
type N = Omit<Car, 'ownerId'> & { ownerId: number }
```

Is this possible to achieve this functionality with TS?

Comment: How are `byDefined` or `byEq` defined? Why does `byOwnerIdEq` have a `string` as parameter when you pass a `number` to it? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @TobiasS. sorry, `byEq` and `byDefined` are just examples of functions I would like to have. Since then I've been able to get even slightly closer to what I want, but generally speaking, I want to be able to provide these helper predicates so that when I want to filter by something somewhere in the code, it's going to tell me that the type is invalid (.e.g., the key doesn't exist in the type).

Comment: The function `byEq` does not know where it is used, so getting an error there on a wrong property is not really possible if you don't provide it information about the full `Car` type.

Comment: @TobiasS. TypeScript knows that the first argument of the function returned by `byEq` should be a `Car`, and can infer the type of everything else from that, as shown by the `composeEqual` function in Arthur's question. See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5YAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG48CwBPABwjJAFcBbAI2iN8AewDuIaAElSybv2jIAPsi4giEGKAhEGBZAHp9yAHSnkwsAAsFmiABsi5HAF8cOGKoRhgwkMj7MACIaWkQAPAAqbBAAfAAUANYQzGRJzMIwyFHsAJTYQshQEGBcUH5xwnwAVmTZEHkAvDH5enpFJWXm1QDaaQC6yACEDQ0qaiESOgXODK44dsXICBjkZOhQ3QOjmwzLUOTIo3vkxpp2kFBxAcGak3EA5GISUNL3OTl0QA).

Comment: @TobiasS. `cars.filter(byDefined('ownerId')).filter(byEq('typed', 1));` works - `byEq` is printed with error that `typed` does not exist in `Car & { ownerId: number }`. Changing the key to `type` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close! Here is a solution using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Note that you can use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) instead of [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) if you want to allow `null` as well.

```
function byDefined<
    Type,
    Key extends keyof Type,
    DefinedType extends {[Property in keyof Type]: Property extends Key ? NonNullable<Type[Property]> : Type[Property]}
>(key: Key) {
    return (obj: Type): obj is DefinedType => {
        return obj[key] !== undefined;
    };
}

/**********************/

interface Car {
    id: string;
    type: number
    ownerId: number | undefined;
    // ... other fields
}

const cars: Car[] = [];
cars[0].ownerId; // number | undefined

const definedCars = cars.filter(byDefined('ownerId'));
definedCars[0].ownerId; // number
```

<kbd>[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwJ4BECmwZkwEwB4AoRMxAFVQAdMAaU8gaU1UUwA8pMx8BnRAGtWcYJRr1GZLDjz4qtdlx79EAbwDaABQBOcWjqhtcQkWIWYAugC5Eu-ZkNtO3XgJZsA-IgByCHyAANoEAhsiBmIQW2noGRpYAfIi20fZxqJYAvsQJABTCqLYeAJTqUog6mFAgOki5cMgAVikSxbYNjYgwAjK4BBaIALxJauXkFVU1SB0aBZaIAISDg4jg%20Nh9%20ADc5Zk72cQA9ABUp2fnF5fHh8TEuNw6wCEQmIgAwiE6ZeMw%20LZ8UB0uAA5jtxkZaLYwCAALbIRzlOAAdzwOgAkn9ENC4Y5EAAfVa8DZyMHkQ6HRAAOmpiDgUAAFricJhAvxiAcIAgAYgIJ8%20LYPjoNPMVsKdrydHwNAAGSyU5GojFbRDkrGw%20FfAlrYkEW6csDc9ayAiCgQrCV8Sk4QIPXJoXpyXIAcgVjgxTuKxR2Rs2pplctd6O2Kop2I1QA)</kbd>